# Microsoft Terminal Services Client (aka Remote Desktop) can I access my remote dual screen from laptop?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I'd like to acess my desktop dual screen pc running xp pro from my single screen latop running xp pro.

I've managed to access my desktop pc with mstc but there doesn't seem to be any way to flick to my other screen on my desktop machine.

I use logmein most of the time, but this tends to use 50% cpu usage and seems a bit overkill when I'm on the same lan.

My aim is to be remote to my desktop pc, which is on the same lan, have good dual screen support and not have a big cpu usage footprint on my desktop?

Comment: Glad I could help @jules!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) it is free, has good dual monitor support, and has a small CPU usage foot print (we run it on embedded machines with 400mhz processor and 256 megs of RAM).

Comment: Dual monitor supports using dual monitors on the client side, not connecting to dual monitors on the host side.

Comment: Ahhh, I was just going to say I can't select that and nothing different shows (aka buttons) on my remote session.

Comment: Well in that case it just compresses it all to one screen anyway @joeqwerty. The Temviewer reference is still valid though.

Comment: @Jules try teamviewer out. Install the host on the pc you are trying to remote to, it has tiny footprint. As I mentioned in my answer I use it on very under powered xp embedded devices.

Comment: Note, Teamviewer is only free for non-commercial/private use.